# AS3 ScrollPane dispatch event to content

Tags: actionscript-3, events, scrollpane

i've loaded external swf into ScrollPane and i need to dispatch click event to this external swf. is it possible? ScrollPane.content.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK,true)); doesn't work. this is obvious cuz ScrollPane.content is an DisplayObject and it have not CLICK event...

I can't use MovieClip as container for external swf cuz external swf is a documents converted to swfs using openoffice and it doesn't want to load inside MovieClip but perfectly loads inside ScrollPane and react on mouse clicks,but i need to simulate mouse click on it.

Answer (score 0):

so you're saying that the following won't work or you haven't tried it?

```
var exSWF:MovieClip = MovieClip( ScrollPane.content );
```

or

```
var exSWF:Sprite = Sprite( ScrollPane.content );
```

Not sure to understand what you mean when you say that your external SWF won't load into a MovieClip.

Do you know what version of Actionscript was used for the external SWF, you can check that in debug mode by looking at the properties of the ScrollPane.content?